# Django: Most efficient Many-To-Many-Relationship addition without through-model?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have to models:

```
class A(Model):
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B)

class B(Model):
    # fields
```

What is the most efficient way to add a large number of existing instances of `B` to the relationship?

Comment: Any specific reason why you need/want to avoid a through-model?

Comment: I have no additional data, so I did not need it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of django 1.4, you can [make use of a `bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) method to create numerous B objects in one go, then add them to the A.b `ManyToMany`

So create a list of `B` objects, bulk create them, then add them [(all at once)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) to the `ManyToMany` relationship of your `A` instance(s):

```
l = [
    B(...),
    B(...),
    B(...),
    ...
]
B.objects.bulk_create(l)
a.b.add(*o)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the `a.b.add(o)` more efficient? By iterating over the entries in the list, django will send an insert for every instance.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can add an unpacked list of objects at once but I think it will still make a DB call on each one

Comment: use "with transaction.atomic():" (from django.db import transaction)